javascript sidebar first link showing always active
I am using below code in this my first sidebar link showing always active even if i click on second third that links working fine as per requirement active move to other link when link but first link always  showing active
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const sidebarWrapper = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');
        const closeButton = document.getElementById('close-sidebar');
        const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

        console.log("Current Path:", currentPath);

        document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar .list-group-item').forEach(function(link) {
            const linkPath = new URL(link.href).pathname;

            console.log("Link Href:", linkPath);

            if (currentPath.includes(linkPath)) {
                link.classList.add('active');
                console.log("Active Link:", link);
            }
        });

        if (closeButton) {
            closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (sidebarWrapper) {
                    sidebarWrapper.classList.toggle('collapsed');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Close button with ID 'close-sidebar' not found.");
        }
    });


From the javascript tag info: "[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ..."

You need to remove "active" class from  matching old url as well as add "active" class to the  that was just clicked on.
You need to do this both when the page loads and when a  is clicked on.
In the future, please provide run able code snippet, so folks that are trying to help you out, do not have create a bunch of html and css to match your Javascript. Thanks.
You can run the code snippet below to see the code and see it working.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  
  const sidebarWrapper = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');
  const closeButton = document.getElementById('close-sidebar');
  // NOTE Change this string to whatever hash name you are using for the first (default) location
  const pageOneHash = "#1"
  
  if( window.location.hash ) {
    document.querySelector( `a[href="${window.location.hash}"]` ).classList.add( "active" )
  }
  else document.querySelector( `a[href="${pageOneHash}"]` ).classList.add( "active" )
  
  
  // Handle in mouse click in the sidebar area
  document.getElementById("sidebar").addEventListener( "click", event => {
    // Only deal with <a> elements
    if( event.target.nodeName == "A" ) {
      // Remove active class from <a> matching current url (url hasn't changed yet)
      if( window.location.hash ) document.querySelector( `a[href="${window.location.hash}"]` ).classList.remove( "active" )
      else document.querySelector( `a[href="${pageOneHash}"]` ).classList.remove( "active" )
      
      // Add the active class to the <a> that was just clicked
      event.target.classList.add('active')
    }
  } )
  
  
  if (closeButton) {
    closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (sidebarWrapper) {
        sidebarWrapper.classList.toggle('collapsed');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Close button with ID 'close-sidebar' not found.");
  }
  
});
#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.collapsed {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#close-sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  min-width: 4rem;
  width: max-content;
}
a, #close-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: Chocolate;
  margin: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: gray solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
  padding: 2px 0px;
}
a.active {
  left: 20px;
  background-color: coral ;
}
<span id="close-sidebar">&#9776;</span>
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div id="sidebar">
            <a href="#1" class="list-group-item">One</a>
            <a href="#2" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
            <a href="#3" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="1">
          <h2>Say one with me.</h2>
          <p>
            Hello
          </p>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        </div>
        <div id="2">
          <h2>Two it is.</h2>
          <p>
            You are here.
          </p>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/210">
        </div>
        <div id="3">
          <h2>Three it be.</h2>
          <p>
            That's it for now.
          </p>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/220">
        </div>



